# open edX multi site setup

Tags: openedx

I tried to configure multiple site with openedx. I have added the new site from /admin/sites/site, and also add site configurations.

It seems I need to modify nginx configuration  under sites-available, but I don't know where the root element should point to for the new site

Here is from sites-available/lms config

location ~ ^/static/(?P.*) {
    root /edx/var/edxapp;

Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: why do you need to modify nginx configuration ? I guess pointing the new site to the ip of old one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  sites-available/lms must be updated to add the new domain.

It has to add new server block

```
server {
  server_name *.newdomain.com

  # error pages
  error_page 504 /server/server-error.html;
  error_page 502 /server/server-error.html;
  error_page 500 /server/server-error.html;

 listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/newdomain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/newdomain.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

...
   # Non-hashed files (there should be very few / none of these)
    add_header "Cache-Control" $cache_header_short_lived always;
  }

}
```